# Using dplyr() to retrieve model object created via group_by() and do()

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use `dplyr` and the pipe operator (`%>%`) to retrieve model objects stored in a dataframe.

With example data

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(256)
dat <- 
  data.frame(x = rnorm(100), 
           y = rnorm(100, 10), 
           spec = sample(c("1", "2"), 100, TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(spec) %>%
  do(lm = lm(y ~ x, data = .))
```

I can subset and retrieve an actual model object

```
> dat$lm[dat$spec == "1"][[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = .)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     9.8171      -0.2292  

> dat$lm[dat$spec == "1"][[1]] %>% class()
[1] "lm
```

But I think this is an inelegant way of retrieving the `lm()` model object contained therein, especially given that the rest of my code is structured the "`dplyr` way". I'd like to use `dplyr` but I can't figure out how. For example, using

```
dat %>% filter(spec == "1") %>% select(lm)
```

doesn't work as it returns

```
Source: local data frame [1 x 1]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 1 x 1
  lm      
  <list>  
1 <S3: lm>
```

and

```
dat %>% filter(spec == "1") %>% .$lm
```

only gets me to the first object in list, e.g.,

```
> dat %>% filter(spec == "1") %>% .$lm
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = .)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
   10.01495     -0.07438
```

I can't figure out a way to get to the actual model object in the `dat` with `dplyr`. Certainly, I could use `broom` and `tidy()` to condense everything

```
library(broom)
tidy(dat, lm)
```

but this still doesn't return the actual model object:

```
> tidy(dat, lm)
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups: spec [2]
  spec  term        estimate std.error statistic                        p.value
  <fct> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>                          <dbl>
1 1     (Intercept)  10.0        0.120    83.3                         1.91e-54
2 1     x           - 0.0744     0.111   - 0.671                       5.05e- 1
3 2     (Intercept)   9.86       0.131    75.0                         1.42e-50
4 2     x           - 0.0793     0.148   - 0.535                       5.95e- 1
```

I can even use `dplyr` to `summarise()` the output from a `do()` call and retrieve the coefficients from the models, but this still doesn't give me the model object itself:

```
dat %>% 
  select(spec) %>%
  bind_cols(dat %>%
              summarize(lm_i = coefficients(lm)[[1]], 
                        lm_s = coefficients(lm)[[2]]))
```

Is there a `dplyr` way to retrieve the actual model object from models created with `do()`?

Comment: It's a list column, so you need to subset it as a list. `purrr::pluck` is one option, e.g. `dat %>% pluck('lm', 1)`

Comment: @duckmayr I thought I was pretty transparent in my question. Really, I don't care which model object, provided I can get one or the other. In my question, I used `spec == 1` as the example, but it could have very easily have been `spec == 2`. Note that I asked how to retrieve "an" rather than "the". Also, when I use `lm1 <- dat %>% filter(spec == "1") %>% .$lm` and try to call `lm1$coefficients`, `NULL` is returned. This does not return a model object.

Comment: `dat %>% filter(spec == "1") %>% .$lm` returns a list of a model. To get the model itself, keep subsetting: `dat %>% filter(spec == "1") %>% .$lm %>% .[[1]]`

Comment: @alistaire Excellent! I learn more about the `tidyverse` everyday. Add as an answer and I'd gladly accept. Also, the `.` in front of the `[[1]]` was what I was missing. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`do` returns a list column, so to extract its individual elements, you need to use list subsetting. There are various ways to do that, but in the tidyverse, `purrr::pluck` is a nice option to extract a single [possibly deeply nested] element:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% pluck('lm', 1)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ x, data = .)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)            x  
#>    10.01495     -0.07438
```

It's mostly equivalent to `[[` subsetting, i.e.

```r
dat[['lm']][[1]]
```

To get what you have to work, you need to keep subsetting, as `.$lm` returns the list column, which in this case is a list of a model. `.[[1]]` (akin to the `1` above) extracts the model from the list:

```r
dat %>% filter(spec == "1") %>% .$lm %>% .[[1]]
```

or a hybrid approach, if you like:

```r
dat %>% filter(spec == "1") %>% pluck('lm', 1)
```

or use `pull` to extract the column with NSE semantics:

```r
dat %>% filter(spec == "1") %>% pull(lm) %>% pluck(1)
```

All return the same thing.